# g++ 4.8.* std::chrono Undeclared

Tags: c++11, gcc

[`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) ought to be supported in `g++ 4.8.*`.  However, when I try to compile using it using `g++ 4.8.3`, it cannot find various declarations.  I am, of course, using `-std=c++11`.

For example this invocation (from an autogenerated file; that's why the `-std` appears twice):

> g++-4.8 -g -msse2 -m64 <defines> <warnings> -std=c++11 -fexceptions -std=c++11 <includes'-path> -c <source-file.cpp> -o <out-path>

Produces this error:

> <source-file, line>: error: ‘std::chrono::monotonic_clock’ has not been declared

I wasn't able to find [very](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2248294) [much](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/144894/) that wasn't immediately a compiler version or missing `-std=c++11`.  By inference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405997/c-chrono-duration-cast-to-milliseconds-results-in-seconds), I shouldn't need anything else.

Question: what's wrong, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `std::chrono::monotonic_clock` in standard C++. There is a [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock), however.

In fairness to Microsoft - and burritos everywhere - [there was a `monotonic_clock` in the working drafts during the development of C++11 which was replaced by `steady_clock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777445/923854).

Comment: Technically, its existence is implementation-dependent.  The code, for example, compiles in MSVC.  Thanks.

Comment: @imallett The standard allows implementations to put additional names in namespace `std` and nested namespaces, so there could well be a `std::chrono::i_like_burritos` in some implementation somewhere. But there is no requirement that namespace `chrono` has a member named `i_like_burritos` (or `monotonic_clock`) in C++11. (Or C++14, which is a shame because I really do like burritos.)

Comment: For sure.  I'm just saying that `std::chrono::monotonic_clock` is a burrito.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could use code like this to determine whether you're using an old library implementation (that provides `monotonic_clock` but not `steady_clock`) or a new one (that provides `steady_clock` but possibly not `monotonic_clock`).

```
#if defined(__GLIBCXX__) && (__GLIBCXX__ < 20120322)
typedef std::chrono::monotonic_clock steady_clock;
#else
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock steady_clock;
#endif
```

The datestamp above corresponds to the libstdc++ shipped with GCC 4.7.0, [according to GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). I'd welcome any improvements or corrections to this code, for example to support libraries other than libstdc++.