# ‘std::chrono::monotonic_clock’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, linux

Does anyone know how to remove the error of `std::chrono::monotonic_clock` in Linux OS (Ubuntu 14.04)? I have the headers of `chrono`, `time` ,`unistd.h` `stdio.h` but the same error shows up.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your operating system, but with which version of the compiler you're using, which you did not state, so no answer is possible. The most likely answer is that your compiler is too old, and does not implement this C++11 class.

Comment: I think you are looking for [std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik The version of my compiler : g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4. And I used "g++ -std=c++11 -o mono_tum mono_tum.cc `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -DECOMPILEDWITHC11" to compile.

Comment: That is an old compiler, that implements very little of C++11. For full support of C++1z, at least gcc 5.3, or higher, is needed.

Comment: @Galik There are two lines in the code. For "std::chrono::steady_clock" there is no error, for ‘std::chrono::monotonic_clock’ I received errors also for t1 and t2.

Comment: @Galik Here is the part of the code, which made an error: #ifdef COMPILEDWITHC11
 std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#else                                                                     std::chrono::monotonic_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::monotonic_clock::now();
#endif
 double ttrack= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(t2 - t1).count();
 vTimesTrack[ni]=ttrack;

Comment: There is no `monotonic_clock` in C++11; there was one in old working drafts, but it got changed into `steady_clock`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik GCC 4.8.4's C++11 support is actually decent - the language is feature-complete, the library just missing a few things.

Comment: @ SamVarschavchik . That's right @T.C. I used also sudo update-alternatives --config g++ and updated my GCC version to 4.8.5. For C++11 support in GCC, it's written in the official website that, more than 4.8 is not needed. https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777278/what-is-the-rationale-for-renaming-monotonic-clock-to-steady-clock-in-chrono

Comment: Thanks @T.C. I have replaced monotonic_clock to steady_clock & the error was removed but I 've got the new error named as : undefined reference.                                                                                                          
mono_tum.cc:(.text+0x880): undefined reference to `ORB_SLAM2::System::SaveKeyFrameTrajectoryTUM(std::string const&)'